# How to push a file automatically from mailparser site to a pythonanywhere server directory

Tags: webhooks, pythonanywhere, email-parsing

I'm new to web development and relatively new to Python coding. I have a mail parser (mailparser.io) that is converting plaintext data patterns from email into a JSON file daily. What is the easiest way to push this file automatically to a pythonanywhere server directory.. I have a paid account with Pythonanywhere..

Comment: I don't know mailparser.io, but if it support scp you try that.  Otherwise, if it uses webhooks, perhaps write a Flask web app on PythonAnywhere to receive them?

Comment: It does use webhooks that i believe it can push the json output to. I'm not familiar with Flask though...

Comment: [There's a PythonAnywhere tutorial that introduces how to use it](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/) -- you probably only need to read the first few sections.